# readlines() without EOL at the of the lines

Tags: python, list, file, io

I want to get a lot of usernames from file - each line is one username. Currently I use this code:

```
lista = []
z = open("usrnames.txt")
lista = z.readlines()
```

But then the results, which are saved in list are:

```
['username1\n', 'username2\n', 'username3\n']
```

I do not want to have EOLs... I except this result:

```
['username1', 'username2', 'username3']
```

How can I do that? I read documentation of this function, and didn't find any argument, which can disable putting EOLs...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could either use list comprehension with `strip`:

```
lista = [line.strip() for line in z.readlines()]
```

or simply, as suggested by @Matthias:

```
lista = [line.strip() for line in z]
```

or use `splitlines`:

```
lista = z.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: And now we should get rid of the `readlines` call: `lista = [line.strip() for line in z]`

Comment: Ok I like `splitlines()` and will use it ! THANKS!